# Change Rectangle Background to Reflect State of Boolean in DataContext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple UI which calls a couple of parsing and processing routines in it's app model that do their work asynchronously through BackgroundWorkers. When the model code is out working, it sets a couple of properties, Parsing and Processing. I have two rectangles in my UI that I want to change color depending on whether those bools are set. The window DataContext is set to the model, and the message list and other parts of the UI are working fine, I just can't seem to figure out how to express what I want to do in XAML.

Here is an example of my rectangle code:

```
<Rectangle Height="20" Name="ParsingLamp" Stroke="Black" Width="20" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="Gray">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="{Binding Path=Parsing}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="ParsingLamp" Property="Fill" Value="LightGreen" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="{Binding Path=Parsing}" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="ParsingLamp" Property="Fill" Value="Brown" />
        </Trigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

I get an error which says "Fill member is not valid because it does not have a qualitying type name."

Perhaps triggers are not the correct way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few problems:

- You need to use a DataTrigger because you're binding to your ViewModel.
- DataTriggers need to be in a Style.
- If you set a local value, e.g. `<Rectangle Fill=''/>` this overrides the value set by the trigger so you need to remove it.

This should work:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LampStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Parsing}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Parsing}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Brown" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Rectangle Height="20" Style="{StaticResource LampStyle}" Stroke="Black" Width="20" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" />
</Grid>
```